# MongoDB: GROUP BY conditionally aggregating COUNT on boolean field

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a three-column collection in Mongo like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db9e1d1b00b1b906c0225"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "hostFqdn" : "host-1",
    "active" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db9e1d1b00b1b906c0226"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.2",
    "hostFqdn" : "host-1",
    "active" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db9e1d1b00b1b906c0227"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.3",
    "hostFqdn" : "host-2",
    "active" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db9e1d1b00b1b906c0228"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.4",
    "hostFqdn" : "host-2",
    "active" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db9e1d1b00b1b906c0229"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.5",
    "hostFqdn" : "host-2",
    "active" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6f61204b0f134f6635a74b"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.6",
    "hostFqdn" : "host-3",
    "active" : false
}
```

I need to select all hostFqdn that has at most one active IP (i.e., for the above data, the response would be `host-1` and `host-3`).

What I've got so far was this:

```
db['hosts.status'].aggregate([[{
    "$group": {
        _id: "$hostFqdn",
        "true": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [{ "$lte": [{ "active": "$active" }, 1]}, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

But this is returning all three hostsFqdn with count 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$hostFqdn",
    "true": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$active", true ]}, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Nice! This returns the amount of active IPs, but what if the host `mta-prod-3`? It does not return with zero count.

Comment: Ok we can remove match stage. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, @Anthony Winzlet

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$hostFqdn',
                status: {
                    $push: '$active'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                v: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $ne: [{
                                $indexOfArray: ['$status', true]
                            }, -1]
                        },
                        then: {
                            $sum: 1
                        },
                        else: 0
                    }
                }



            }
        },

    ]

    // Created with Studio 3T, the IDE for MongoDB - https://studio3t.com/

);
```